# Add all the numbers which have + symbol and replace the same with the added value

Tags: java, regex

I would like to group all the numbers to add if they are supposed to be added.

- Test String: '82+18-10.2+3+37=6 + 7
- Here 82+18 cab be added and replaced with the value as '100.
- Then test string will become: 100-10.2+3+37=6 +7
- Again 2+3+37 can be added and replaced in the test string as
  follows: 100-10.42=6 +7
- Now 6 +7 cannot be done because    there    is a space after value
  '6'.

My idea was to extract the numbers which are supposed to be added like below:

- 82+18
- 2+3+37

And then add it and replace the same using the replace() method in string

Tried Regex:

```
(?=([0-9]{1,}[\\+]{1}[0-9]{1,}))
```

Sample Input:

```
82+18-10.2+3+37=6 + 7
```

Java Code for identifying the groups to be added and replaced:

```
    import java.util.regex.Matcher;
    import java.util.regex.Pattern;

    public class ReplaceAddition {

        static String regex = "(?=([0-9]{1,}[\\+]{1}[0-9]{1,}))";
        static String testStr = "82+18-10.2+3+37=6 + 7 ";

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE);
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(testStr);

            while (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println(matcher.group(0));
                for (int i = 1; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
                    System.out.println(matcher.group(i));
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Output:

- 82+18
- 2+18
- 2+3
- 3+37

Couldn't understand where I'm missing. Help would be appreciated...

Comment: which language are you using ?

Comment: I'm trying to do in Java

Answer (score 1):

I tried simplifying the regexp by removing the positive lookahead operator

```
(?=...)
```

And the enclosing parenthesis

```
(...)
```

After these changes, the regexp is as follows

```
static String regex = "[0-9]{1,}[\\+]{1}[0-9]{1,}";
```

When I run it, I'm getting the following result:

```
82+18
2+3
```

This is closer to the expected, but still not perfect, because we're getting "2+3" instead of 2+3+37. In order to handle any number of added numbers instead of just two, the expression can be further tuned up to:

```
static String regex = "[0-9]{1,}(?:[\\+]{1}[0-9]{1,})+";
```

What I added here is a non-capturing group

```
(?:...)
```

with a plus sign meaning one or more repetition. Now the program produces the output
    82+18
    2+3+37
as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is like so:

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    final var p = Pattern.compile("(?:\\d+(?:\\+\\d+)+)");
    var text = new StringBuilder("82+18-10.2+3+37=6 + 7 ");
    var m = p.matcher(text);
    while(m.find())
    {
        var sum = 0;
        var split = m.group(0).split("\\+");
        for(var str : split)
        {
            sum += Integer.parseInt(str);
        }
        text.replace(m.start(0),m.end(0),""+sum);
        m.reset();
    }
    System.out.println(text);
}
```

The regex `(?:\\d+(?:\\+\\d+)+)` finds:

```
(?:                  Noncapturing  
   \\d+              Any number of digits, followed by 
       (?:               Noncapturing
          \\+            A plus symbol, and
             \\d+        Any number of digits
                 )+      Any number of times
                   ) Once
```

So, this regex matches an instance of any number of numbers separated by '+'.